# urlencoding is not working and redirecting to new record in lightning

Tags: visualforce, sforce, forcenavigatetourl, url-encode

In apex class via soql getting record id owner name but it is not redirecting in lightning to new record page and prepopulate values.

```
    urlString = '/lightning/o/AssetRegular__c/new/?defaultFieldValues=';
    urlString += ownerId;
    urlString = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(urlString, 'UTF-8');
```

in Vfpage

```
 <apex:page standardController="Asset" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" recordSetVar="opp" extensions="assetRegularController">
  <script>
    sforce.one.navigateToURL(urlString);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I presume you have a `public String urlString { get; set; }` in your Apex. Given this, the VF should have:

```
<script>
    sforce.one.navigateToURL('{!JSENCODE(urlString)}');
</script>
```

Second, you wouldn't URL Encode an entire URL, as that would be inappropriate here. You would want to encode the ownerId if it could have invalid values, but... it shouldn't, presumably. So you don't need:

```
// Do not do this!
// urlString = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(urlString, 'UTF-8');
```